# Evaluate number once compare twice in one statement

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

Easy question... Is there any way to do a where clause comparing a number to two numbers in one statement? Something like this:

```
where 1000 > 500 > 300
```

The reason is, if I need to evaluate the 500 and it's expensive this would save a lot of time over the alternative:

```
where 1000 > 500
  and 500 > 300
```

Comment: I think you need to look at the query plan for your above query and the solution offered below. The actual path taken may well be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write

```
where 500 between 301 and 999
```

or

```
select a,b,c from (
   select a,b,c, 500 as d from ....
) where 1000 > d and d > 300
```

but there is also hope that the database is clever enough to figure out that it has to do the calculation only once.

Answer (score -1):

If computing 500 is expensive, just evaluate it once and store its value.
Then compare this value to 1000 and 100.

Comment: I do believe he was asking HOW to do that :)